# Launch VB form from a C# form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

A friend of mine and me were working on a project for class. He prefers VB and I prefer C#, so we just did our thing. Now, we were thinking of merging the projects. I added his into mine, but I can't find how to open the forms he has made from the forms I made.

Is there any way to launch VB forms from a C# form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to mix C# in VB. but you can use approach suggested by Jon Skeet.

1) [Create Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78.aspx)

- [How to: Create Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h970wzkb.aspx)

2) Add Reference of your friend's VB project in your project

- [How to: Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)

Then you can create object of those forms that your friend created as:

```
YourFriendProject.SomeForm  someForm = new YourFriendProject.SomeForm();
someForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 7):

Language is project specific.  Meaning you have a C# project and VB project.  You cannot mix multiple languages in one project.  You can however have multiple languages projects in a solution.  E.g he does the front-end in VB and you do the back end in c# and then add references in the vb project to the c# project.

Additionally, you could use a VB to C# converter or vice versa with mixed results.  I've converted entire vb projects to c#.

Comment: But the problem is that we've both made forms, thinking we wouldn't be merging it. I know that you can add C# dll's to a VB project and the other way around. But I would like to open his forms. (Or am I just not understanding you)

Comment: I believe you could open his form from the dll if it's exposed as public.  One project will have to be the "master" that will do the application loading though.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into that :) Or maybe just translating and recreating his forms.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add different languages to the same project, but you should be able to add both projects to the same solution, and add a reference from your C# project to his VB project, and use the types he's created - so long as they're public, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has already been posted, just adding a picture to make things a bit more clearer.

- You cannot add forms / code from two different languages to the same project.
- You can add a project reference from the VB assembly to the CS assembly and vica versa.
- You can add either project to the other solution to have access to both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. C# opening VB.NET. I also added sCarletto as a reference, but trying to add my main C# for as a reference to sCarletto, I wasn't so successful...yet. On voice command Araura (form1) opens sCarletto (vb.net) form.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaSVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a real simple solution I overlooked due to being burnt out on coding.
I simply did this:

```
Case "ARAURA COME BACK"
Process.Start("The file path to my C# programs .exe located in the Debugging folder")
me.Close()
```

Comment: Sorry for the separation issue above. I had it spaced out beneath each other, but it spit it back this way. You can find my projects at:  github.com/deadreport77