# C# code within VB.NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

i have one application which is build using **VB.NET** now

i required to add some **C# code** inside my existing **VB.NET** application does it **possible** or **not**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a seperate project for the C# code.  Then place a reference to C# project into the VB.Net project.  You can then access the C# objects as if they were written in VB.Net

Answer (score 3):

> You can't add different languages to the same project, but you should
>   be able to add both projects to the same solution, and add a reference
>   from your C# project to VB project or VB project to C# project, and use the types he's created
>   - so long as they're public, of course.

Follow this approach:
1) [Create Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78.aspx)

- [How to: Create Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h970wzkb.aspx)

2) Add Reference of your CSharp project in your project

- [How to: Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)

Then you can create object of those Class/Forms etc and access methods that you created in CSharp project as:

```
Dim obj As New YourCSharpProject.SomeClass()
obj.UpdateData()
```

Ref: [Launch VB form from a C# form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704358/launch-vb-form-from-a-c-sharp-form/9704570#9704570)

Answer (score 2):

No.  You will need to create a separate project within your solution and place the code in that.  If the project is a class library then your original project can reference that and call the library routines.
Failing that, there are plenty of online C#<->VB.NET converters available.

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, you cannot directly intermix the two languages because a compiler will only understand the language it is written for. Hence, a VB.NET compiler cannot understand C# code unless MS creates an extension to do so. Something like this comes from my imagination :) -

```
Dim v as int
%for(int i = 0; i < $v; ++i){}%
```

Comment: something like below code snippet...                             `static class Program {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    static void Main()
    {
        if (true)                                
        {
            //do some things, for example starting the service.
        }
        else 
        {
            AllocConsole();
        }           
     }        
 }`

Comment: DllImport will expose methods from unmanaged code. Using that you can use c/c++ functions from your vb.net/c# code. Refer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213045/how-can-i-call-c-sharp-extension-methods-in-vb-code

Comment: Bottomline is that you cannot directly intermingle these two languages in a source file. You have to seperate (put in a DLL) and import (import the DLL by referencing it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it's a seperate class / page / webcontrol / usercontrol and it's specified as C#. Visual Studio will not like it, and the easy way in VS is to setup a new project within the solution.

Comment: Means if i have a complete separate C# class than i could call function of C# class files..from VB class file????? thank you so much for answering....

Comment: No you need a separate C# *project*.  The only way I've seen of mixing languages within the same project is within the App_Code folder of an ASP.NET project.

Comment: Or if you're using a website, and just a "new web site..." then you can add classes, pages, usercontrols etc. of either language (which is where the `App_Code` folder comes into play).

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a little C# code, you can first convert it to VB.NET with a converter like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/, or you can convert it manually.

Otherwise, as already noted, you'll have to put the C# code in another project in the same solution.  You can then call the C# code from your VB.NET code in the same solution.